# Teaching IDA to keep column width in xrefs window, or shortcut to quickly adjust them?

Tags: ida

When invoking the function xrefs in IDA (8.2.230124), I can adjust the column widths and sorting or even the dialog size (here I adjusted only the width of the *Address* column):

[image: Adjusted width of the Address column]

IDA appears to remember the dialog size and position, but lets me start over every single time in regard to the other mentioned properties, such as the column width:

[image: Columns being reset every time]

Is there a way to do either of the following:

1. teach IDA to remember the column widths and sorting of that dialog window?
2. use a quick keyboard shortcut to get the desired "optimal" column width and sorting?

NB: the weird thing is that even though it remembers the dialog size, IDA doesn't even seem to use up the horizontal size of the dialog for the columns, instead shortening a column such as the *Address* one with an ellipsis.